# Pattern of upgrades Clash Royale

Tags: clash-royale

I was wondering if there was an algorithm or pattern to how much health/damage/minion level is gained per level up.

For example, a level 7 cannon will have 616HP and deal 105DMG per shot. But a level 9 will have 742HP and deal 127DMG per shot. Is there a statistical increase between these values or are they instead pre-programmed by the developers?

Comment: I would imagine that some algorithm does exist to scale up the stats of each card. However, unless its been reversed engineered or released by the developers theres no way of knowing what it is. I would argue that this question should be closed because it's asking about developer intent, but I think its kind of a grey area.

Comment: Please see my answer, it has been calculated to be around 10% per level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Cards) it says that:

"All health and damage statistics are increased by **roughly 10% per level**. "

Emphasis mine.

In your case we have.

```
616 x 1.1 x 1.1 = 745

105 x 1.1 x 1.1 = 127
```

It seems fairly close.